# pandas: Calculate the difference from a grouped average

Tags: python, pandas

I have sensor data for multiple sensors by month and year:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
 ['A', 'Jan', 2015, 13], 
 ['A', 'Feb', 2015, 10], 
 ['A', 'Jan', 2016, 12], 
 ['A', 'Feb', 2016, 11], 
 ['B', 'Jan', 2015, 7],
 ['B', 'Feb', 2015, 8], 
 ['B', 'Jan', 2016, 4], 
 ['B', 'Feb', 2016, 9]
], columns = ['sensor', 'month', 'year', 'value'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
    sensor month  year  value
0      A   Jan  2015     13
1      A   Feb  2015     10
2      A   Jan  2016     12
3      A   Feb  2016     11
4      B   Jan  2015      7
5      B   Feb  2015      8
6      B   Jan  2016      4
7      B   Feb  2016      9
```

I calculated the average for each sensor and month with a groupby:

```
month_avg = df.groupby(['sensor', 'month']).mean()['value']

In [3]: month_avg
Out[3]:
sensor  month
A       Feb      10.5
        Jan      12.5
B       Feb       8.5
        Jan       5.5
```

Now I want to add a column to `df` with the difference from the monthly averages, something like this:

```
    sensor month  year  value  diff_from_avg
0      A   Jan  2015     13    1.5
1      A   Feb  2015     10    2.5
2      A   Jan  2016     12    0.5
3      A   Feb  2016     11    0.5
4      B   Jan  2015      7    2.5
5      B   Feb  2015      8    0.5
6      B   Jan  2016      4    -1.5
7      B   Feb  2016      9    -0.5
```

I tried multi-indexing `df` and `avgs_by_month` similarly and trying simple subtraction, but no good:

```
df = df.set_index(['sensor', 'month'])
df['diff_from_avg'] = month_avg - df.value
```

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`assign` new column with `transform`

```
diff_from_avg=df.value - df.groupby(['sensor', 'month']).value.transform('mean')
df.assign(diff_from_avg=diff_from_avg)

  sensor month  year  value  diff_from_avg
0      A   Jan  2015     13            0.5
1      A   Feb  2015     10           -0.5
2      A   Jan  2016     12           -0.5
3      A   Feb  2016     11            0.5
4      B   Jan  2015      7            1.5
5      B   Feb  2015      8           -0.5
6      B   Jan  2016      4           -1.5
7      B   Feb  2016      9            0.5
```

Comment: Dang! Too quick for me! I should definitely start using `assign`, if only to write out answers quicker!

Comment: This looks excellent, but I'm getting an unhelpful error on the first line: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transform'`.  Any idea what this could mean?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I use `assign` because I don't like clobbering the `df`.. Especially when i might very well time the operation.

Comment: To answer my own comment: it worked when using bracket notation:
`diff_from_avg=df.value - df.groupby(['sensor', 'month'])['value'].transform('mean')`

Comment: @robroc that is because you don't have a column named `'value'`... This should run on your sample data.  Please verify that it works on the dataframe you provided.  Then figure out what is different in your actual data from the data you provided.

Comment: @robroc out of curiosity, what version of pandas are you using?  `pd.__version__`

Comment: @piRSquared v. 0.18.1

Comment: @robroc does everything run now?  With your change?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 df['diff_from_avg']=df.groupby(['sensor','month'])['value'].apply(lambda x: x-x.mean())
Out[18]:
  sensor month  year  value  diff_from_avg
0      A   Jan  2015     13            0.5
1      A   Feb  2015     10           -0.5
2      A   Jan  2016     12           -0.5
3      A   Feb  2016     11            0.5
4      B   Jan  2015      7            1.5
5      B   Feb  2015      8           -0.5
6      B   Jan  2016      4           -1.5
7      B   Feb  2016      9            0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the index of the DataFrame to be consistent with the grouped Series, then you can subtract directly:

`df.set_index(['sensor','month'], inplace=True)
df['diff'] = df['value'] - month_avg`